# how to get the xpath from popup which is occur in the same window?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to send the values to this pop up. this is open with in the same window. when am trying with the normal driver.findelement, its getting error message saying xpath cannot found
This is my code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Homepage_login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        //driver.get("http://se.rdmsonline.net/login.aspx");

        driver.get("http://se.rdmsonline.net/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rcmLang_Arrow']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rcmLang_DropDown']/div/ul/li[2]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtUserName']")).sendKeys(" ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys(" ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Div1']/div/a")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtUserName']")).sendKeys(" ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys(" ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rptSec_ctl00_imb']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Menu5']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cpl1_lnkNewNotification']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cplm_dtpDate_dateInput_text']")).sendKeys(" ");



    }

}
```

this to be send the control inside the pop up.. can any one help me ?

Comment: Refer [this to understand how to images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question)...

Comment: i tried to attached the screenshot Amith, since am newly entered, i dont have 10 reputations. so i cant add the images. i share the code. if you run the code then you can see my showstopper point

Answer (score 0):

First you should switch to the popup and then try to find the element.
You can use following code snippet

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   String handle = iterator.next();
   if (!handle.contains(parentWindow)) {
                    // Switch to popup 
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                    // Add code to find element 
       }
}
// Switch back to original window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

This code will work with any number of popups

Comment: Thanks for your response Karna, since this is not opening with the new window, do we need to switch? i tried with your code as well. but still i couldn't pass the control

Comment: @user3512119 Even for popup you need to switch the control. Add my code once popup appears

Comment: @Ajinkya is there a PowerShell equivalent to this code?

Comment: @konalion Not sure, dont know much about PowerShell.